# How can I filter an array of objects based on a hash of conditions in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I want to pass hash:

```
filter_search = {age: 20, weight: 30, height: 30, salary: (100000..200000)}
```

to method

```
def search(array, filter)
  array.select do |elem|
     ???????
  end
end

filtered_array = search(some_array, filter_search)
```

How can I do this? Maybe I'm thinking in wrong way and there is another pattern to solve this?

Comment: It's really unclear what you are trying to ask...

Comment: Is the array parameter an array of objects that have the appropriate methods (age, weight, height, salary) and you want to return a filtered array of the ones that perfectly match your hash filter.

Comment: The title and the question do not match.

Comment: @ShadowRadiance, Yes, this is exactly what I need

Comment: A better title might be "How can I filter an array of objects based on a hash of conditions in Ruby?"

Comment: @SlavaNikulin If my answer helps, then please mark it as accepted. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the array parameter an array of objects that have the appropriate methods (age, weight, height, salary) and you want to return a filtered array of the ones that perfectly match your hash filter, something like this might work.

```
def search(array, filter)
  array.select do |elem|
    filter.all? do |key, value|
      elem.send(key) == value
    end
  end
end
```

If you have hashes in your array instead of objects, you would use:

```
def search(array, filter)
  array.select do |elem|
    filter.all? do |key, value|
      elem[key] == value
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Yep, thank you. I've just tested, and it works! Sorry for my bad English and Ruby)